# Sleep command in windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm going to write a batch script in windows server 2008. The script is a general windows commands and it needs waiting for few minutes before executing the next line of the script somewhere in the middle. When I tried `sleep`, it said command not found. Is the command replaced with some other command or if not, how could I install it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sleep.exe is just an executable from the W2K3 RK, no install is required. I don't see why it wouldn't work on W2K8. Download and extract the W2K3 RK, copy sleep.exe to the W2K8 server, add it to system path environment variable, and put it in your batch file.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD&displaylang=en

Comment: Will it work if extract w2k3 RK in w2k8?

Comment: I don't see why not, but you'll have to try it to make sure.

Comment: I'll definitely try this

Answer (score 11):

In Windows Server 2008 R2, the command to be used is "timeout" which replaces "sleep"

C:\Windows\System32\timeout.exe /T 10 /nobreak

Comment: Could you give some examples that how to use timeout?

Answer (score 3):

Move to the preferred scripting language for Win2K8 which is Powershell.  The Start-Sleep cmdlet will do just what you are looking for.

Comment: I heard It's possible in powershell but don't know how I could call powershell in batch file.

Comment: Just call the Batch with "& NAMEOFBATCHFILE" (without quotes)

Answer (score 1):

As workaround you can make an ping -n 60 localhost (its not exactly a minute but you can guess how long) or you create an small vbs and call it with cscript sleep.vbs

```
wscript.sleep dauer
```

As far as i know there is no sleep command within the windows series. Only thing is powershell where sleep is supported.

Comment: It may be possible as you said with `@ping -30 127.0.0.1` in the batch and I should try this

Comment: Sorry!. The command is `ping -n <no in seconds> 127.0.0.1>nul`

Answer (score 1):

timeout is the correct command in windows server 2008 and windows 7
You can get help by typing timeout /? on the command prompt
If you would like to use ping then try this
ping -w 5000 -n 1 1.0.0.0
This will wait appromiate 5 seconds